# How to parse spatial data from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, geospatial

I am trying to get results of spatial data from mysql into json form and I get this output for the same linestring:

```
`[[-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],[-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]] `
```

But I need to get this:

```
`[{" coordinates":[[-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583], [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]]}`
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
    <?php

require_once("caroom_db.php");

header("Content-Type: application/json");
    //$l1 = '';
    $ll1 = array();
    //$lt = array();

 $json_response = array();

       $ll =0;
    //echo $l;
    $jsonData = '[';
    $num_point="SELECT NumPoints(geo_type) FROM line_park WHERE id='2'";
    $query = mysqli_query($cn, $num_point) or die (mysqli_error($cn)); 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


                    $ll  = $row["NumPoints(geo_type)"];
//echo $ll;
}

    for ($i=1; $i<=$ll; $i++) {

    $l1="SELECT X(PointN(geo_type,$i)), Y(PointN(geo_type,$i)) FROM line_park";



            $query = mysqli_query($cn, $l1) or die (mysqli_error($cn)); 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $ll1[0] = $row["X(PointN(geo_type,$i))"];
        $ll1[1] = $row["Y(PointN(geo_type,$i))"];


                array_push($json_response,$ll1);


            }


        }

        echo json_encode($json_response);

fclose($cn);


?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try to convert an array to json using http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php pushing your values into an array would be simpler

Comment: OK, thanks for you comment. I did not try using json-encode, but this seems reasonable option. I will let you know about the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since my comment solved your problem I'm posting it as an answer so you can accept. Try to convert an array to json using php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php pushing your values into an array would be simpler.

To add `coodrinates` just do string concat

```
$jsonData = json_encode($json_response);
$jsonData = '{"coordinates":' . $jsonData . '}';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another array key. For example,

```
json_encode(array('coordinates' => $response));
```